# Как связать форму входа с другой страницой

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, form

Как связать две страницы между собой?

Например, есть страница входа, где запрашивается имя пользователя, и вторая страница, где используется (отображение, вывод и т.д) имя, введенное при входе.
Пример, при клике на add-name запоминается введенное значение и, по идее, должен быть переход на следующую страницу, как это правильно реализовать? И не будет ли конфликтов с двух страниц, использующий один и тот же код (файл, прост переменные другие будут)?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var name = "";

  $("#add-name").click(function() {
    name = $("#name").val();

    if($("#name").val() == "") {
      alert("Введите имя");
      return false;
    }

    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <form id="form" action="#" method="POST">
    <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Введите имя">
    <input id="add-name" type="submit" value="Продолжить">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приветствую!
Если без использования **PHP** то вариантов не много.

1. **JavaScript** работает только на конкретной странице и понятия не имеет, что происходит на соседних. Параметр передавайте через
   **URL:** `<a href="next-page.html?name=вася">click</a>` А на next-page.html распарсите `location.href`. Только **method** в форме замените на **GET**, вместо **POST**.
2. Использовать какой-нибудь плагин для работы с **cookie**, вроде [js-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) после отправки формы сохраните данные туда, а на нужной странице извлекайте. Но размеры **cookie** сильно ограничены. Как в принципе и тело **GET** запроса для варианта 1, так что особо не увлекайтесь. :)
3. Старый, добрый **PHP**.

Comment: А если name сохранять в localstorage? а как потом input указать ссылку? например, сперва проверяются введенные данные, после данные сохраняются в localstorage и после этого происходит переход по ссылке. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Можно и в localStorage, или sessionStorage, с той лишь разницей, что session после закрытия вкладки очищается, как и любая сессия. На тему localStorage есть просто отличная статья: ["LocalStorage на пальцах"](https://tproger.ru/articles/localstorage/). Ознакомьтесь, если что-то будет непонятно, спрашивайте! ;)